# Laravel Where Collection

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, lumen, laravel-collection

I am having troubles with laravel collections. This is my script:

```
foreach($getResult->all()['results'] as $key => $val) {
  $colVal = collect($val);

  $dataDiff = [];
  $getWithoutLine = $colVal->except(['line_items']);
  $getDiff = $colVal->only(['line_items']);

  foreach($colVal->all()['line_items'] as $val1) {
    if ((int)$val1['quantity'] - (int)$val1['deliveries']['quantity'] > 0) {
      $getWithoutLine['status'] = 'partially_received';
      $dataDiff[] = $val1;
    }
  }

  $getWithoutLine['line_items'] = $dataDiff;
  //dd($getWithoutLine);
  $filtered = $getWithoutLine->whereStrict('status', 'submitted');
  //dd($filtered->all());
  $getFullCol[] = $filtered;
}
```

When `dd($getWithoutLine)` is executed, then collection appears like this:

```
Collection {#464
  #items: array:24 [
    "id" => "13c023aa-b471-4276-a0fc-a22d3677be91"
    "status" => "submitted"
    "date" => "2018-09-19"
    "time" => "11:54:22"
    "number" => "PO000003"
    "description" => "Pesanan Pembelian, Vendor 1"
    "supplier" => array:4 [
      "id" => null
      "code" => null
      "name" => null
      "classification" => null
    ]
    "term_of_payment" => array:6 [
      "due_date" => null
      "due_days" => 0
      "late_charge_rate" => 0.0
      "discount_date" => null
      "discount_days" => 0
      "early_discount_rate" => 0.0
    ]
    ...
    ...
  ]
}
```

But when `dd($filtered->all())` is executed then the result is empty. Why is that?

I can't understand what I am doing wrong.

=======
EDITED

When I change `dd($filtered->all())` to `dd($filtered)` the result is actually same :

```
Collection {#463
  #items: []
}
```

======
EDITED

When I Change `$filtered = $getWithoutLine->whereStrict('status', 'submitted');` to `$getWithoutLine->only('status');` the collection is work...

```
Collection {#468
  #items: array:1 [
    "status" => "submitted"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you try dd($filtered->get()) ?

Comment: `Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\\Support\\Collection::get()` @SapnaBhayal

Comment: you can't do $filtered->all() you must do $filtered->get() it will return all data that fit the query

Comment: `Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\\Support\\Collection::get()` I am using lumen @IamCavic

Comment: can you change $getWithoutLine->whereStrict('status', 'submitted'); to $dataStuff->whereStrict('status', 'submitted'); and than try $filtered->all()

Comment: I above don't work try this:
`//$getWithoutLine['line_items'] = $dataDiff;
  //dd($getWithoutLine);
  $filtered = $getWithoutLine->whereStrict('status', 'submitted');
  dd($filtered->all());`

Comment: didnt work too @IamCavic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180404/discussion-between-i-am-cavic-and-nasihun-amin-suhardiyan).

Comment: anyone cant help me?